# Disabling options in django-autocomplete-light

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

Just started using django-autocomplete-light (autocomplete.ModelSelect2) and while I have managed to get it working, I wondered if it is possible to pass disabled options?

I have a list of customers to choose from but some, for various reasons, shouldn't be selected they shouldn't be able to use them. I know I could filter these non-selectable customers out, but this wouldn't be very usable as the user might think that the customer isn't in the database. If so, could someone point me in the right direction as I'm not sure where to start.

It says in the [Select2](https://select2.org/options#disabling-options) documentation that disabling options should be possible. Presumably if I could also send a 'disabled':true within the returned json response that might do it.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so here is what I came up with and it works.

**view.py**

The Select2ViewMixin is subclassed and then a 'disabled' attribute is added to the customer details. This value provided by the ParentAutocomplete view.

```
from dal import autocomplete
from dal_select2.views import Select2ViewMixin
from dal.views import BaseQuerySetView

class CustomSelect2ViewMixin(Select2ViewMixin):
    def get_results(self, context):
        return [
            {
                'id': self.get_result_value(result),
                'text': self.get_result_label(result),
                'selected_text': self.get_selected_result_label(result),
                'disabled': self.is_disabled_choice(result), # <-- this gets added
            } for result in context['object_list']
        ]

class CustomSelect2QuerySetView(CustomSelect2ViewMixin, BaseQuerySetView):
    """Adds ability to pass a disabled property to a choice."""

class ParentAutocomplete(CustomSelect2QuerySetView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Customer.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(org_name__icontains=self.q)

        return qs.order_by('org_name', 'org_city')

    def get_result_label(self, item):
        return item.selector_name

    def get_selected_result_label(self, item):
        return item.selector_name

    def is_disabled_choice(self, item): # <-- this is where we determine if the record is selectable or not.
        customer_id = self.forwarded.get('customer_id', None)
        return not (item.can_have_children and not str(item.pk) == customer_id)
```

**form.py**
The form is then used as normal.

```
from dal import autocomplete

class CustomerBaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    customer_id= forms.IntegerField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        widgets = {
            'parent':autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
                url='customer:parent-autocomplete',
                forward=['customer_id'],
            )
        }
```

Hopefully this might be useful to someone.